# Which file is supported by Microsoft Mesh app?

Tags: mesh, hololens, 3d-model

The Microsoft Mesh app on Hololens 2 allows loading files from the local device. I want to load 3D models to my workspace, but don't know which types of 3D models are supported. I have tried .fbx files but had no success.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:
"For 3D content, only .glb files are supported at this time. We currently have a file size limit of 75MB, or maximum 300,000 vertex count for 3D models. If these limits are exceeded, you will fail to load your content, and get a warning: "This model is too complex"."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mesh/mesh-app/use-mesh/import-content#import-user-content